# What does the syntactic sugar <<= mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am seeing variable declared

```
lazy val liquibase = TaskKey[Liquibase]("liquibase", "liquibase object")
```

Then I am seeing this below

```
liquibase <<= ( liquibaseChangelog, liquibaseDatabase ) map {
    ( cLog :String, dBase :Database ) =>
      new Liquibase( cLog, new FileSystemResourceAccessor, dBase )
  }
```

It looks like its adding functionality to the `TaskKey`?

Comment: Might be library defined. Check their documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala it means nothing, it's a DSL defined by [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/).

In your case what it's doing is defining `liquibase` in terms of the values assigned to `liquibaseChangelog` and `liquibaseDatabase`, therefore adding a dependency on them. See ["Computing a value based on other keys' values"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values) for some more detail.

---

Futhermore, as of sbt 0.13 you can write this in a nicer, clearer way:

```
liquibase := {
  val fs = new FileSystemResourceAccessor
  new Liquibase(liquibaseChangelog.value, fs, liquibaseDatabase.value)
}
```

---

As a sidenote, you may find [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com) handy -- it's a search engine that respects special characters like `<<=`